# Is it Possible to Apply the panelOnDestroyCallback Callback Parameter to the force:editRecord Event by Updating the $A Namespace?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-recordeditform, modal, callback

#### Is it possible to update a copy of the [`$A` namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_jsapi_dollarA.htm) object to handle callbacks where they are not otherwise handled?

For example, the [`force:createRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord/documentation) event has the `panelOnDestroyCallback` callback function that allows us to perform a function when the Create Record modal is closed:

```js
$A.get('e.force:createRecord').setParams({
  entityApiName: 'ExampleObject__c',
  panelOnDestroyCallback: () => { // <-- This is not available for force:editRecord
    console.log('The Create Record modal has been closed!');
  },
}).fire();
```

On the other hand, the [`force:editRecord`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:editRecord/documentation) event does not have this callback available.

Is it possible to create a copy of the callback from one event and apply it to another event?

**For example, is it possible to apply the `panelOnDestroyCallback` callback parameter from `force:createRecord` to the `force:editRecord` event?**

Here's an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish:

```js
(function () {
  const $createRecord = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
  const $editRecord = $A.get('e.force:editRecord');
  
  // Something like this?
  $editRecord.handleParam['panelOnDestroyCallback'] = $createRecord.handleParam['panelOnDestroyCallback'];
  
  $editRecord.setParams({
    recordId: 'a00XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    panelOnDestroyCallback: () => {
      console.log('The Edit Record modal has been closed!');
    },
  }).fire();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

In summary, this shouldn't be possible. Anything not documented must be presumed impossible. Your best bet would be to suggest an Idea on the [IdeaExchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).